# Two Left Outer Join

Tags: sql

I have two tables in this form:

Inventory:

```
Units   InDate OutDate

1000     11/4   12/4

2000     13/4   14/4
```

Prices:

```
Date Price
11/4    5
12/4    4
13/4    6
14/4    7
```

I want to build the following table:

```
Units   InDate OutDate InPrice   OutPrice

1000     11/4    12/4     5       4

2000     13/4    14/4     6       7
```

I thought I should use something like:

```
Select *
FROM Inventory
LEFT OUTER JOIN Prices ON Inventory.InDate = Prices.Date
LEFT OUTER JOIN Prices ON Inventory.OutDate = Prices.Date
```

But the second OUTER JOIN seem to mess things up.

How can I reach this result?

Answer (score 4):

```
Select
  Units,   
  InDate,
  OutDate,
  P1.Price as InPrice,
  P2.Price as OutPrice
FROM Inventory
LEFT OUTER JOIN Prices as P1 ON Inventory.InDate = P1.Date
LEFT OUTER JOIN Prices as P2 ON Inventory.OutDate = P2.Date
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
SELECT Inventory.Units, Inventory.InDate, Inventory.OutDate, InPrices.Price AS InPrice, OutPrices.Price AS OutPrice
FROM Inventory
LEFT OUTER JOIN Prices AS InPrices ON Inventory.InDate = InPrices.Date
LEFT OUTER JOIN Prices AS OutPrices ON Inventory.OutDate = OutPrices.Date
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current query was very close to being correct.  If you placed different aliases on the `prices` table then it would have worked.  Since you are joining on the same table `prices` twice, you need to use a different alias to distinguish between them:

```
select i.units,
  i.indate,
  i.outdate,
  inPrice.price,  
  outPrice.price
from inventory i
left join prices inPrice  -- first join with alias
  on i.indate = inPrice.date
left join prices outPrice  -- second join with alias
  on i.outdate = outPrice.date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a64/2)